# Reset lightning-record-edit-form values to passed-in values

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I am using a `lightning-record-edit-form` to create a campaign. I am defining the default value for a rich text field using a variable:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Campaign" onsubmit={showSuccessToast}>

  <lightning-input-field field-name="Message__c" value={defaultText}></lightning-input-field>

  <lightning-button type="button" label="Reset" onclick={resetFields}></lightning-button>

</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation), I should be able to reset my fields to these initial values using this snippet:

```
resetFields(evt) {
  this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach(field => field.reset());
}
```

But I end up having all fields cleared out instead of having the initial values populated.
What's the clean way to really reset these values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292393/reset-the-lightning-input-to-its-default-value

Comment: unfortunately not, my variables stay unchanged, so this would not trigger a rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is that your code sets `value={defaultText}` in the template? So that even if you try to use salesforce reset, it doesn't show the default value you had.

Try the following in controller

```js
const DEFAULT_TEXT = "your value here";

export default class CampaignForm extends LightningElement {
    defaultText = DEFAULT_TEXT;
    resetFields = () => {
        this.defaultText = DEFAULT_TEXT;
    }
}
```